Code runner extension runs my code slowly
I've started learning C and installed Code Runner and the C debugger as I saw in the tutorial. When I run my code it takes the extension about 15 seconds to print something as simple as "Hello world". I ran Python code using the extension, it ran in less than a second.
I tried enabled "run in terminal" which didn't help at all.

What OS? Try adding this directory to antivirus exceptions, if you have one. Make sure your directory is not on google drive.

@HolyBlackCat I'm using Windows. I made sure to check the directory of the file and it's not on Google Drive.
